# How do I convert a list of tuples with sets to a dictionary?

Tags: list, tuples, python, set

I have this dataset. I want to update the MySQL table. I can do it in the current form but I thought a conversion to dictionary will shrink the list to be updated.

**My dataset :**

```
dataset = [('121', set(['NY'])), ('132', set(['CA', 'NY'])), ('198', set(['NY'])), ('676', set(['NY'])), ('89', set(['NY', 'CA']))]
```

**Desired output :**

A dictionary :

```
output = {'set(['NY'])':121,198,676, 'set(['CA', 'NY'])':132,89}
```

Comment: Do you want the sets to be keys or do you want a string representation of the set to be the key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ***must*** use a frozenset for the key. There is no guarantee that a set with the same elements will always be turned into the same `repr` or `tuple` as sets are unordered. Unless you sort the set elements first of course, but that seems wasteful

```
from collections import defaultdict

dataset = [('121', set(['NY'])), ('132', set(['CA', 'NY'])), ('198', set(['NY'])), ('676', set(['NY'])), ('89', set(['NY', 'CA']))]
output = defaultdict(list)
for value, key in dataset:
    output[frozenset(key)].append(value)
```

or using a sorted tuple

```
from collections import defaultdict

dataset = [('121', set(['NY'])), ('132', set(['CA', 'NY'])), ('198', set(['NY'])), ('676', set(['NY'])), ('89', set(['NY', 'CA']))]
output = defaultdict(list)
for value, key in dataset:
    output[tuple(sorted(key))].append(value)
```

Random example to illustrate this

```
>>> s,t = set([736, 9753, 7126, 7907, 3350]), set([3350, 7907, 7126, 9753, 736])
>>> s == t
True
>>> tuple(s) == tuple(t)
False
>>> frozenset(s) == frozenset(t)
True
>>> hash(tuple(s)) == hash(tuple(t))
False
>>> hash(frozenset(s)) == hash(frozenset(t))
True
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can have a `set` as a dictionary key, so maybe a tuple?

```
from collections import defaultdict

dataset = [('121', set(['NY'])), ('132', set(['CA', 'NY'])), ('198', set(['NY'])), ('676', set(['NY'])), ('89', set(['NY', 'CA']))]
output = defaultdict(list)
for value, key in dataset:
    output[tuple(key)].append(value)
    # or output[str(key)].append(value) if you want a string as the key
```

Comment: You can if you use a frozenset

Comment: @jamylak, frozenset for sure as `sets` are unordered

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataset = [('121', set(['NY'])), ('132', set(['CA', 'NY'])), ('198', set(['NY'])), ('676', set(['NY'])), ('89', set(['NY', 'CA']))]
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for val, key in dataset:
    d[repr(key)].append(int(val))

d
> {"set(['NY', 'CA'])": [132, 89], "set(['NY'])": [121, 198, 676]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to `defaultdict`:

```
dataset = [('121', set(['NY'])), ('132', set(['CA', 'NY'])), ('198', set(['NY'])), ('676', set(['NY'])), ('89', set(['NY', 'CA']))]    

output = {}
for value, key in dataset:
   output.setdefault(frozenset(key), []).append(value)
```

Result:

```
>>> output
{frozenset(['NY', 'CA']): ['132', '89'], frozenset(['NY']): ['121', '198', '676']}
```

I prefer using `setdefault()` over `defaultdict` here because of the following behavior:

```
>>> output = defaultdict(list, {frozenset(['NY', 'CA']): ['132', '89'], frozenset(['NY']): ['121', '198', '676']})
>>> output[frozenset(['FL'])]    # instead of a key error, this modifies output
[]
>>> output
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {frozenset(['NY', 'CA']): ['132', '89'], frozenset(['FL']): [], frozenset(['NY']): ['121', '198', '676']})
```